# Flutter : Call value from second function class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Auth class which has sgin in function and inside of this function value for example user value , so how to get this value from Auth class to Home class ?

Here Auth class and Home Class :

```
class Auth {
  void signIn(){
    String user = "I LOVE PROGRAMMING";
  }
}

class Home {

  return Text("$user") //Iwant user value from clas AUTH

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to have the `signIn` function return the user.

```
class Auth {
  String signIn() {
    String user = "I LOVE PROGRAMMING";
    return user;
  }
}
```

Then you can call that from another class:

```
class Home {
  Widget someFunction() {
    final auth = Auth(); // create a new instance of Auth
    final user = auth.signIn(); // call the function and put the return value in a `user` variable
    return Text(user); // use the `user` String in the Text widget
  }
}
```

I would advice you to have a look at the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and learn about these things step by step. These are the basics you will need to get anything done. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You should be implement below way

```
class Auth {
  static String _user;

  void signIn() {
    _user = "dfsdfgdfgfdgdfgfdgfdgfdgfd";
  }

  static String getUser() => _user;
}



class Home {

  return Text(Auth.getUser()) 

}
```

Comment: I think ,It will work and it will return null if not called singIn() method

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you need to create a global variable for the String user that you have set in the Auth class and create a getter for it. You also would need to use some type of state management to simulate the value changes. In this case I'll use the provider package.

```
class Auth extends ChangeNotifier{
    String _user = '';
    void signIn() {
        _user = 'SomethinInteresting';
    }
    String get userName => _user;
}
```

Whenever the signIn() function is being called from other component, the value for the user would be set. And finally if you want to access the value from other component you can use the getter to set the value in the Text component.

```
class Home {
  final _auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return text(_auth.userName);
  }
}
```

This would also facilitate dyanmic changes to the fields in the Auth class.

Answer (score -1):

For accessing the value from the "Auth" class you first need to make the method type String and return the value when the method is called. In the Home class there must be main method as it is from where the execution of the program starts. Now, create an object of class "Auth" and call the method using the same object. You'll get the user value.

```
class Auth {
  String signIn(){
    String user = "dfsdfgdfgfdgdfgfdgfdgfdgfd";
    return user;
  }
}

class Home {
    public static void main(String args[]){     
     Auth ob=new Auth();
     System.out.println(ob.signIn());//I want user value from clas AUTH
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing but this is java code , my code is for flutter.